# Passing Components as children through a main Form component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm relatively new to React and redux. Loving it but I'm having problems passing components into other components as children and getting them to display. I'm currently working with a massive Form.js file with all the panels there but it would be easier to maintain to have them as separate components.

I have a large client data form. Each section for the form is in a tab/panel format. It would be great to be able to have each tab panel as a separate component, but I can't seem to get each panel to show by passing them through as children.

Page.js

```
// file imports....

// constructor, handleChange, handleSubmit, 


render() {
    return <div className="page">
        <div className="page-content">

            <Form {...this.state}
                onChange={this.handleChange} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

                <Details {...this.state} onChange={this.handleChange} />

            </Form>

        </div>
    </div>
}
}

export default Page
```

Form.js

```
// file imports....




const Form = ({ client, errors, onChange, onSubmit }, props) => {

  function handleChange(name, value) {
    if (value !== client[name]) {
      onChange(name, value)
    }
  }

  return <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>

        <Heading client={client} />    
        <TabNavigation />  

        <div className="tab-content">


          {props.children}  



          </div>
        </form>

}

Form.displayName = displayName
Form.propTypes = propTypes

export default Form
```

Details.js

```
// file imports....



const Details = ({ client, errors, onChange }) => {

    function handleChange(name, value) {
        if (value !== client[name]) {
            onChange(name, value)
        }
    }
        return(
        <div className="tab-pane active animation-slide-left" id="details" role="tabpanel">


                  ............   more form data  .........
            </div>

        </div>




    )

}

Details.displayName = displayName
Details.propTypes = propTypes

export default Details;
```

Comment: your question is not clear. could you please post minimal code to understand the problem better?

Comment: removed functions and imports,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `...` syntax to get the rest of the props properly.

```
const Form = ({ client, errors, onChange, onSubmit , ...props}) => {
```